# Add text to layout in Android Studio (Beginner)

Tags: android

I am trying to include text in my layout but it doesn't show up in Design or Blueprint. In Blueprint, it just shows up as a dot (encircled in red in the picture). I tried opening the default text in the "hello world" app which works on my phone, but the same problem occurs in the layout in Android Studio.

I am following the guide at this link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.

I've included a screenshot for reference. If this helps, please note that the emulator is not running in Android Studio and the layout / design screen does not display fully in the window when I select Pixel XL 5.5 screen (it's too large and I can't scroll down to see it).

I also do not get the square box in the Blueprint as shown in figure 3 of the webpage (link above). [Screenshot of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxxUM.jpg)

**EDIT : Following is the code for my activity_main.xml file -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="36dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:text="TextView"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:3"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add the code of your layout xnl file here.

Comment: Show me your xml file

Comment: Looks like you haven't given proper width and height attributes. Just a guess! It can be rectified if you share your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues. You're using ConstraintLayouts, but you're constraints are a little mixed up. In the first `TextView`, you have your `topToTopOf` constraint set to `parent`, which is fine, but your bottom constraint is also set to `topOf` `parent`. Change your bottom constraint to `bottomToBottomOf` `parent`. Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

In your second `TextView`, you're using `dimensionRatio` wrong. It states in the `ConstraintLayout` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints) that you can only use this attribute with `H` or `W` if both of your width and height are set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` (aka `0dp`). So for example, you've set the `dimensionRatio` to `h,1:3`, but this only works if your width is set to `0dp` (aka `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`). You should either make the width `0dp`, set the height explicitly, or change your `dimensionRatio` to `1:3` rather than `h,1:3`

Comment: I'm able to see the text on the emulator, but not on Android Studio. The Design Screen is still empty and the Blueprint screen is still showing a tiny dot. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: If you're seeing it in the emulator but not in the design screen, the design screen is probably not showing correct information. In the top left corner of the design screen, there's a dropdown where you select whether to show the design, the blueprint or both, and at the bottom it should have an option to force refresh of the layout. Click on that and see if it changes what you see.

Comment: I fixed it. It's weird, but it's related to the theme of the app. For some reason, the default 'AppTheme' doesn't work for me.